# A command-line calculator using infix to postfix in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math-expression-eval

I was in the mood for some C++ and decided to write a command line calculator, which understands addition, subtraction, multiplication and parentheses. See what I have:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::copy;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::isspace;
using std::ostream_iterator;
using std::pair;
using std::runtime_error;
using std::stack;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::vector;

enum class TokenType {
    OPERAND,
    OPERATOR
};

enum class Operator {
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    MULTIPLY,
    LEFT_PARENTHESIS,
    RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
};


static int get_operator_precedence(Operator _operator)
{
    switch (_operator) {
        case Operator::PLUS:
        case Operator::MINUS:
            return 1;

        case Operator::MULTIPLY:
            return 0;

        default:

            if (_operator == Operator::LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
            {
                throw runtime_error(
                    "Left parenthesis has no precedence assigned to it.");
            }

            if (_operator == Operator::RIGHT_PARENTHESIS)
            {
                throw runtime_error(
                    "Right parenthesis has no precedence assigned to it.");
            }

            throw std::runtime_error(
                    "Unknown operator. This should not happen.");
    }
}

class Token
{
    TokenType m_token_type;
    Operator  m_operator;
    int       m_operand;

public:
    Token(int operand) : m_operand{operand},
                         m_token_type{TokenType::OPERAND} {}

    Token(Operator _operator) : m_operand{0},
                                m_token_type(TokenType::OPERATOR),
                                m_operator{_operator} {}

    TokenType get_token_type() const
    {
        return m_token_type;
    }

    Operator get_operator() const
    {
        return m_operator;
    }

    int get_operand() const
    {
        return m_operand;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Token&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Token& token)
{
    if (token.m_token_type == TokenType::OPERAND)
    {
        out << token.m_operand;
    }
    else
    {
        switch (token.m_operator)
        {
            case Operator::PLUS:
                out << "+";
                break;

            case Operator::MINUS:
                out << "-";
                break;

            case Operator::MULTIPLY:
                out << "*";
                break;

            case Operator::LEFT_PARENTHESIS:
                out << "(";
                break;

            case Operator::RIGHT_PARENTHESIS:
                out << ")";
                break;
        }
    }

    return out;
}

vector<Token> tokenize(const string& expression)
{
    vector<Token> token_vector;
    stringstream number_string_stream;
    bool number_string_stream_empty = true;
    size_t char_index = 0;
    size_t expression_length = expression.length();

    while (char_index < expression_length)
    {
        const char current_char = expression[char_index];

        switch (current_char)
        {
            case '(':

                if (!number_string_stream_empty)
                {
                    int number;
                    number_string_stream >> number;
                    number_string_stream.clear();
                    token_vector.push_back(Token(number));
                    number_string_stream_empty = true;
                }

                token_vector.push_back(Token(Operator::LEFT_PARENTHESIS));
                break;

            case ')':

                if (!number_string_stream_empty)
                {
                    int number;
                    number_string_stream >> number;
                    number_string_stream.clear();
                    token_vector.push_back(Token(number));
                    number_string_stream_empty = true;
                }

                token_vector.push_back(Token(Operator::RIGHT_PARENTHESIS));
                break;

            case '+':

                if (!number_string_stream_empty)
                {
                    int number;
                    number_string_stream >> number;
                    number_string_stream.clear();
                    token_vector.push_back(Token(number));
                    number_string_stream_empty = true;
                }

                token_vector.push_back(Token(Operator::PLUS));
                break;

            case '-':

                if (!number_string_stream_empty)
                {
                    int number;
                    number_string_stream >> number;
                    number_string_stream.clear();
                    token_vector.push_back(Token(number));
                    number_string_stream_empty = true;
                }

                token_vector.push_back(Token(Operator::MINUS));
                break;

            case '*':

                if (!number_string_stream_empty)
                {
                    int number;
                    number_string_stream >> number;
                    number_string_stream.clear();
                    token_vector.push_back(Token(number));
                    number_string_stream_empty = true;
                }

                token_vector.push_back(Token(Operator::MULTIPLY));
                break;

            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':

                number_string_stream_empty = false;
                number_string_stream << current_char;
                break;

            default:
                if (!isspace(current_char))
                {
                    stringstream err_msg;

                    err_msg << "Bad character: '"
                            << current_char
                            << "' at index "
                            << char_index
                            << "!";

                    throw runtime_error(err_msg.str());
                }
        }

        ++char_index;
    }

    if (!number_string_stream_empty)
    {
        int operand;
        number_string_stream >> operand;
        token_vector.push_back(Token(operand));
    }

    return token_vector;
}

vector<Token> shunting_yard_algorithm(const vector<Token>& token_vector)
{
    vector<Token> postfix_token_vector;
    stack<Token> operator_stack;

    for (const Token& token : token_vector)
    {
        if (token.get_token_type() == TokenType::OPERAND)
        {
            postfix_token_vector.push_back(token);
        }
        else if (token.get_operator() == Operator::LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
        {
            operator_stack.push(token);
        }
        else if (token.get_operator() == Operator::RIGHT_PARENTHESIS)
        {
            while (!operator_stack.empty()
                   && operator_stack.top().get_operator()
                   != Operator::LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
            {
                postfix_token_vector.push_back(operator_stack.top());
                operator_stack.pop();
            }

            if (operator_stack.empty()
                || operator_stack.top().get_operator()
                        != Operator::LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
            {
                throw runtime_error("The parentheses are invalid.");
            }
            else
            {
                operator_stack.pop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (!operator_stack.empty()
                   && operator_stack.top().get_operator()
                        != Operator::LEFT_PARENTHESIS
                   && get_operator_precedence(
                        operator_stack.top().get_operator()) <
                        get_operator_precedence(token.get_operator()))
            {
                postfix_token_vector.push_back(operator_stack.top());
                operator_stack.pop();
            }

            operator_stack.push(token);
        }

    }

    while (!operator_stack.empty())
    {
        postfix_token_vector.push_back(operator_stack.top());
        operator_stack.pop();
    }

    return postfix_token_vector;
}

pair<int, vector<Token>> coderodde_evaluate(const string& expression)
{
    vector<Token> infix_token_vector = tokenize(expression);
    vector<Token> postfix_token_vector =
        shunting_yard_algorithm(infix_token_vector);

    stack<Token> _stack;

    for (const Token& token : postfix_token_vector)
    {
        if (token.get_token_type() == TokenType::OPERATOR
            && token.get_operator() == Operator::LEFT_PARENTHESIS)
        {
            throw runtime_error(
                "The parentheses are invalid.");
        }

        if (token.get_token_type() == TokenType::OPERAND)
        {
            _stack.push(token.get_operand());
        }
        else
        {
            if (_stack.size() < 2)
            {
                throw runtime_error("The parentheses are invalid.");
            }

            int operand2 = _stack.top().get_operand(); _stack.pop();
            int operand1 = _stack.top().get_operand(); _stack.pop();

            switch (token.get_operator())
            {
                case Operator::PLUS:
                    _stack.push(Token(operand1 + operand2));
                    break;

                case Operator::MINUS:
                    _stack.push(Token(operand1 - operand2));
                    break;

                case Operator::MULTIPLY:
                    _stack.push(Token(operand1 * operand2));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (_stack.size() != 1)
    {
        throw runtime_error("The parentheses are invalid.");
    }

    return make_pair(_stack.top().get_operand(), postfix_token_vector);
}

int main()
{
    string expr;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "> ";
        getline(cin, expr);

        if (expr == "quit")
        {
            break;
        }

        try {
            pair<int, vector<Token>> data = coderodde_evaluate(expr);
            cout << "Value: " << data.first << ", postfix notation: ";

            copy(data.second.cbegin(),
                 data.second.cend(),
                 ostream_iterator<Token>(cout, " "));

            cout << endl;
        }
        catch (runtime_error& err)
        {
            cout << "ERROR: " << err.what() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

Am I doing good C++ here? Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: Cases 1, 2, ..., 9 may be simplified

Comment: Title should possibly include whether it is a prefix, infix or postfix calculator.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thank you for your input. I made the title more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite nice. A couple of small things:

- you can use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` when adding Tokens. Likewise for the stack with `emplace` instead of `push`
- for the sake of symetry, do `out << 'c'` instead of `out << "c"`
- check your IO: your mainloop should be `while (getline(cin, expr)) { ... }` to detect `EOF`
- don't use `_variable` for names.

Comment: So `emplace_back` will **move** the object instead of copy-constructing it?

Answer (score 2):

This suggestion probably won't make the code look more like C++.

Parsing, tokenizing input is very cumbersome job. It has a lot of edge cases. When possible, very high quality library should be deployed. It might be overkill, but one of them is [boost.spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) family of libraries. It is based on [expression templates](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template).

You're `using` too much. The only case you should write `using` is switch statement, which is done to let the compiler choose appropriate function overload. Just write `std::` where it should be written.

Don't use m_ prefixes. They are artifacts of the past. Good reason to enrich vocabulary (but don't write too sophisticated words so other people could understand ).

Answer (score 2):

**Descriptive function names**

It's kind of weird to name your parsing after yourself `coderodde_evaluate`.  It suggests it's evaluating you (unless coderodde has some meaning I don't know about).  I'd prefer a name that describes what the function actually does.  If you want to package your stuff, think about using namespaces instead.

**The parentheses are invalid.**

You throw runtime errors with the string same string 'The parentheses are invalid.' 4 times in your code.  This suggests that maybe it should be defined as a constant.  It's also, somewhat confusing to the user:

```
> 1*
ERROR: The parentheses are invalid.
> *
ERROR: The parentheses are invalid.
>
ERROR: The parentheses are invalid.
```

I haven't used any parentheses...

**Overflow checking**

You don't limit the size of the input stream, so it's possible to overflow the input:

```
> 11111111111111111111
Value: -858993460, postfix notation: -858993460
```

**Spaces**

This is probably subjective, but I find it odd that you allow spaces between numbers:

```
> 2*(2 1 3 4 5 6 7)
Value: 4269134, postfix notation: 2 2134567 *
```

**Enum Values**

Again, somewhat subjective, but I'd be tempted to assign values to your operator enum like:

```
enum class Operator {
    PLUS='+',
    MINUS='-',
    MULTIPLY='*',
    LEFT_PARENTHESIS='(',
    RIGHT_PARENTHESIS=')'
};
```

That way the value of the enum is actually linked to the character it represents.  This makes it possible for your `operator<<` to become:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Token& token)
{
    if (token.m_token_type == TokenType::OPERAND)
    {
        out << token.m_operand;
    }
    else
    {
        out << static_cast<char>(token.m_operator);
    }
    return out;
}
```